# Conditional File Logic in Linux

Tags: file-permissions, ksh

I have written some code below to find files that are not readable by the current user. It is giving me messages that the files can't be read in the subdirectories of the parent folder, even though I explicitly tested at the bottom of the script outside of the loop for one of the files it reports as not readable. However, I've checked and all the files have the group permissions set to allow reading and I've used vi to open several of them. What is going on here?

Script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -A files $(ls -1 $1)
echo "${#files[@]}"

for((i=0; $i < ${#files[@]}; i++)); do
  if [ ! $2 ${files[$i]} ]; then
    echo "${files[$i]} not $2"
  fi
done

echo "============"
if [ ! -r ./tmp/feederseries.txt ]; then
  echo "./tmp/feederseries.txt not readable"
fi
```

Output:

```
$ testfiles.sh "*" -r
212
./buildhist: not -r
20170109_124058.txt not -r
20170109_124128.txt not -r
./cmpatches: not -r
tmp.txt not -r
./reports: not -r
archived not -r
./tmp: not -r
feederseries.txt not -r
============
```

Comment: just add `ls -l ${files[$i]}` to debug the inputs? Also, typcial unix/linux cmd-line options would expect something like `-r` to be first. Then you don't need to quote `"*"`, just let the cmd-line naturally expand the list of files to be processed. Also, I'm surprized that output of `ls -l $1` includes "files ..... in the subdirectories of the parent folder", I don't think it will. Maybe I'm misunderstanding. Would be better if you created a small 4 file sample with 1 subdir with  1 file that we could test the problem.  Good luck.

Comment: Using `echo "$i: ${files[$i]}"` to debug the input inside the for loop shows what ULick mentioned that the files in subdirectories are being input into the array without their sub-directory paths, so when the file test is done, it is looking for the file in the wrong location.  When the asterisk is not quoted, the shell expands it before feeding it to the script, which means that the `-r` is the last argument (i.e. argument $213). I could probably switch the order of the arguments to prevent that, as you said the order is not typical.

Comment: `ls -l` will list subdirectories when the file argument is `*`. Because I want the script to be flexible to be able to search for patterns (i.e. `*.sh`) or all files, I had to feed it an argument `ls -l $1`; however, this means that to search for all files, I have to assign something to the argument that will catch all files. Unfortunately, this also tells `ls` to list subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is not needed to do this. Using `ls` to loop through a filelist is anyway not the best idea. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29 for explanation.

With `ls -1 *` you get a list of files in the actual directory, the subdirectories followed by ':' and the files in the subdirectories. The files in subdirectories are reported as non readable, because they don't exist in the actual directory (where you do the test).

Let the shell take care of expansion and iterate through the list:

```
#!/bin/ksh
for file in $1; do
    if [ ! $2 $file ] ; then
      echo "$file not $2"
    fi
done
```

If you just need the files which are not readable, this would do:

```
find .. ! -perm /u=r -print
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips to make the script work. I actually stumbled upon `find`'s ability to test permissions afterwards, but I'm glad you didn't just tell me to use `find`, as I wanted to know where my misunderstanding was in my construction of this script. You highlighted some important points about looping through files and the link you suggested is very helpful. Thank you!